# check data if is equal from 2 foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i want to check my data like this

data source result from foreach

```
Data Source => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
```

my data for result from foreach is:

```
ID_1 => 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 13, 15
ID_2 => 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

how method to check if id is same or equal with data source will result true but if id not have the datasource the result will be false?

here my code to foreach the data

```
        @php
            $items = array();
            foreach($activity as $a){
                $items[] = $a->id;
            }
            $list = implode(', ', $items); 
        @endphp
        Data Source => {{ $list }}


        @foreach($result as $detail_activity)
            ID_{{$detail_activity->id}}  => {{$detail_activity->ActivityDetail}}<br>
        @endforeach
```

with the result like this

if we use that example data, maybe like

```
data source | id_1 | id_2 |
1             False True
2             False True
3             False True
4             True  True
```

thanks for advance :D

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: i already edit the post :D

Comment: Is the data source and those 2 arrays always sorted?

Comment: yea already sorted

Comment: Any update....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved thanks for every response from you all... sorry if I take a long response

first we create a function

```
function checkfacility($facility,$datasource){
                        foreach($datasource as $ds){
                            if($facility == $ds->name){
                                return true;
                            }   
                        }
                    }
```

then we made a foreach with condition at blade template like this

```
@foreach ($facility as $key => $values)
   <td>{{ (checkfacility($values->name,$datasource)) == TRUE ? 'true' : 'false' }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$dataSource` is an array, e.g.

```
$dataSource = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 ];
```

And assuming `$id_1` and `$id_2` are arrays, e.g.:

```
$id_1 = [ 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 13, 15 ];
$id_2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ];
```

To determine whether each element in `$dataSources` exists in `$id_1` or `$id_2`:

```
foreach ( $dataSource as $id ) {
    echo $id,
    ( in_array( $id, $id_1 ) ? 'True' : 'False' ),
    ( in_array( $id, $id_2 ) ? 'True' : 'False' ),
    "\n";
}
```

The better way would be to store the info in the *keys* of `$id_1` and `$id_2` and then use the expression `$id_1[$id]` since that would be faster than `in_array()`.

Comment: but i mean is to compare an array, if the id_1 or id_2 is not in datasource the result must be false, btw id _1 and id_2 is result from foreach.. it must be nested foreach?

Answer (score 1):

We first create a `helper` that tells us whether a value exists in a `sorted` array using [`binary search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (for fast searches).

**Helpers.php:**(add this file in `bootstrap` folder)

```
<?php

function has($needle,$haystack){
    if(!isSorted($haystack)){
        throw new Exception("Sorted array expected but unsorted array given.");
        return;
    }

    $low = 0;
    $high = count($haystack) - 1;
    while($low <= $high){
        $mid = $low + intval(($high - $low) / 2);
        if($haystack[$mid] === $needle) return true;
        if($haystack[$mid] > $needle) $high = $mid - 1;
        else $low = $mid + 1;
    }

    return false;
}

function isSorted($haystack){
    $keys = array_keys($haystack);
    foreach($keys as $index => $key){
        if($index - 1 >= 0 && $haystack[$key] < $haystack[$keys[$index-1]]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

To make these functions available in your project, you need to edit the `composer.json` like below in the `autoload` section:

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
           "bootstrap/helpers.php" // <--- this line
        ]
    },
```

Now, do a **composer dump-autoload** to autoload this file.

The blade code would be pretty straightforward like below:

```
@foreach($data_source as $val)
    @if(has($val,$ID_1))
        <p>{{ $val }} => ID_1 true</p>
    @else
        <p>{{ $val }} => ID_1 false</p>
    @endif
    @if(has($val,$ID_2))
        <p>{{ $val }} => ID_2 true</p>
    @else
        <p>{{ $val }} => ID_2 false</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```